# Should npm global install in AppData\Roaming?

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-8, npm

I am trying to install Jade globally using `npm` so that I can use the Jade watcher in WebStorm.

```
npm install jade --global
```

However, I can only find `jade.cmd` in:

```
...\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and

```
...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jade-watch\node_modules\.bin\jade.cmd
```

This doesn't seem right... shouldn't there be an entry under `Program Files` I can reference?

Comment: Looks like npm is installed for your user, rather than for the whole system, so in that case it probably makes sense?

Comment: Good point, that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with that strategy too...

There is some sense and justification but i would prefer that the modules installed globally stayed in the NPM folder.

But seems that this is a large debate, see here -> [@github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4564)